# Selenium Following-Sibling

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find the xpath of an input field using following-sibling but not getting the correct xpath. Kindly suggest

http://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/
(userid = admin@yourstore.com || Password = admin)

Click on catalog > Categories > Add New

Here - I am trying to find the xpath of the select field opposite to Limited to customer roles and my xpath is `//label[text()='Limited to customer roles']/following-sibling::div` but it is not working. Also, I tried `xpath = //div[@class='k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap']` but it is displaying 3 comman xpaths but my requirement is to find the select field opposite to Limited to customer roles only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"//label[text()='Limited to customer roles']//ancestor::div[@class='col-md-3']/following-sibling::div//div[@class='col-md-4']/div"
```

Click on this div displays the dropdown.

Comment: Can you please also explain me the logic you used for deriving this xpath which will help me to understand it and handle the same situation when i face it again. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hard to explain on here... Google for xpath axes for explanation on ancestor, following parts etc. Rest is basic xpath. There are tons of youtube videos on selenium webdriver locators. Check them out.